# Навигационная панель. Убрать через touch

Tags: java, android

Навигационная панель появляется при слайде снизу вверх. Нужно чтобы при таче на экран приложения, панель свернулась обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через функцию:

```
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

[Вот](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) так же есть документация по вашему вопросу. [Вот](https://gist.github.com/gelldur/cf7ff0d0d026dbd743d0) есть отдельно написанный класс на гитхабе. [Вопрос1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity) + [Вопрос2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218490/androidshow-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-programmatically-while-in-immersive) по вашей теме.